# Get jquery Map from input attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dictionary

i have a set of inputFields looking like :

```
<g:textField name="adrstrasse" data-id="adressen[${i}].strasse" class="newaddr" id="daten_vornametarea" value="${adresse.strasse}"/>
<g:textField name="adrort" data-id="adressen[${i}].ort" class="newaddr" id="daten_vornametarea" value="${adresse.telefon}"/>
<g:textField name="adrtelefon" data-id="adressen[${i}].telefon" class="newaddr" id="daten_vornametarea" value="${adresse.telefon}"/>
```

and i want to return those as a stringified map,

doing so :

```
var addrmap = $('.newaddr').map(function() {
        var $item = $(this);
                return {
        name: $item.data('id'), 
        value: $item.val()
    };
    }).get();
    var neu = JSON.stringify(addrmap); 
    alert(neu);
```

I´m getting a map looking like :

```
[{"name":"adressen[0].strasse","value":"Hanswarft1"},{"name":"adressen[0].ort","value":"Hallig Hooge"},{"name":"adressen[0].telefon","value":"12345678"}]
```

But I want it to look like :

```
[{"adressen[0].strasse":"Hanswarft1"},{"adressen[0].ort":"Hallig Hooge"},{"adressen[0].telefon":"12345678"}]
```

When I try something like this, ofcourse i get syntax errors

```
    var addrmap = $('.newaddr').map(function() {
        var $item = $(this);
                return {
        $item.data('id'):
        $item.val(),
    };
    }).get();
    var neu = JSON.stringify(addrmap); 
    alert(neu);
```

How do I return the map with data-id as parameter and value as value ? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Your last update completely altered the question

Comment: yes it did, ah i have to rethink it anyway, so dint try to answer this, igor dymov gave the perfect answer

Comment: I rollbacked the question. Otherwise, question and answer won't fit together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That might do the job:

```
var addrmap = $('.newaddr').map(function () {
    var $item = $(this);
    var obj = {};

    obj[$item.data('id')] = $item.val();
    return obj;
}).get();
```

Comment: yeah thats the totally correct answer to my question, thanks alot,this made me, unfortunetly, recognize i need the map to look even more difficult i updated my question